# DialogFragment overwrite style when returning to foreground

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am stuck trying to overwrite the style in a DialogFragment when the fragment is shown after it was backgrounded at least once.

This is the relevant code:

My `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog.Default">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_background</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyDialog.NoAnimation"
    parent="Theme.MyDialog.Default">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
</style>
```

My Fragment relevant portion of the code:

```
private boolean wasPaused;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (wasPaused) {
        // when this dialog re-enters foreground, do not animate it
        super.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.Theme_MyDialog_NoAnimation);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    wasPaused = true;

    super.onStop();
}
```

The style is never `R.style.Theme_MyDialog_NoAnimation` even after the dialog fragment comes back into foreground after being backgrounded. The debug statements show that the `super.setStyle(...)` does happen but my guess is it occurs after the view is already created. Can the style be overwritten after the app was paused?

UPDATE: see my comment which includes the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

Based on javadoc comments at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/DialogFragment.java

`Calling setStyle(int, int) after the fragment's Dialog is created will have no effect.`

Hopefully this will help someone else.